# Choose subset of points with geometry closest to orginal

Tags: algorithm, geometry, dynamic-programming

I have list `n (n < 500)` of positive integers representing elevation profile. I need to choose at most `m (m < 255)` points of them to make new geometry as similar as orginal one as possible. For input `[10, 21, 15, 2, 8, 35, 94, 223, 370, 575, 701, 661, 592, 356] and m = 8` I want to return `[10, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 94, 0, 370, 575, 701, 0, 592, 356]` (`0` means that we skip that number). Because when we connect points by lines we have geometry `[10.0, 9.5, 9.0, 8.5, 8.0, 51.0, 94.0, 232.0, 370.0, 575.0, 701.0, 646.5, 592.0, 356.0]`, errors for points are `[0.0, 11.5, 6.0, 6.5, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 14.5, 0.0, 0.0]` so the maximum error is `16`

I tried dynamic programming approach where `dp[i][j]` was solution for array starting not earlier than at `i` position and using not more than `j` elements. To compute it for every `k` from `i` to `n` I compute maximum error if `k` is the first element and take maximum of it and `dp[k + 1][j - 1]`.

Can we spend `O(1)` time for every `k` to calculate maximum distance from points `[i .. k - 1]` to line connecting points `i - 1` and `k`? Does anyone have idea how to solve whole problem in `O(n^2)`?

Comment: Is it assumed that the first and last points are always picked, in order to be able to interpolate across the whole range? Or you can leave them out and extrapolate them from the closest values?

Comment: Frankly speaking I'm not sure, I think we may leave them out.

Comment: What is 'm' here ? You are saying when m = 8, I want to return [10, 0, 0....] which is of length more than 8.

Comment: @SomeDude `m` is the number of data points from the original set to keep, if I understand the question correctly. The 0's are just placeholder values. (There really should be a 'placeholder' entry in the array other than a 0 as this could get confusing)

Comment: @Alerra you're right, I forgot to mention and choosed wrong example because it's guaranteed that number are positive.

Comment: Do you want to choose the anchor points from the input or can you also choose arbitrary anchor points to reduce the error? Do you want the absolute-difference error like in your question or is a squared distance also fine (or even more appropriate)?

Comment: We need to choose points from the input. I think you're right squared distance would be better, generally speaking there is no hard requirement for error function.

Comment: It's ether *sum* of squares or  maximum absolute value. Maximum square doesn't make a lot of sense (same result as maximum absolute value). Sum of absolute values is sometimes (rarely) appropriate.

Comment: If 'close enuough', rather than closest, will do you might want to try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm

Comment: @dmuir, there are two problem with Ramer–Douglas–Peucker for me:
- I need to specify maximum error, which I don't know 
- I cannot specify that I want my curve to fit in 255 elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O(n^2 log n) is doable for the maximum error objective. At a high level, we compute the maximum error for each of the O(n^2) line segments, sort these values, and then use binary search over the possible error limits and breadth-first search in the directed acyclic graph of points that can follow other points given an error limit to determine the minimum maximum error. Each of these three steps takes O(n^2 log n) time. The space usage is O(n^2).

To determine the maximum error for each line segment, we repeat the following O(n log n) procedure once for each of the O(n) points as the left endpoint. Maintaining an upper and lower hull of the points scanned so far (using Andrew's variant of the [Graham scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan)), scan each of the possible right endpoints in order. Use binary search on the upper (respectively, lower) hull to find the point whose preceding line segment has slope greater than (respectively, less than) or equal to the line connecting the endpoints currently being considered and whose succeeding line segment has slope less than (respectively, greater than) that. This point is the farthest above (respectively, below) the line segment.

Comment: Could you explain in more details bfs part? I computet maximum error for each segment, then sort it line by line. When I perform bfs my first node is curve from points [0], its neighbours are curvers from points [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], .. [0,n] (but there are sorted by max err). How do we mark visited nodes?

Comment: @stawny Once you've guessed a maximum error, you use BFS to figure out if it's achievable. The nodes of the graph correspond to the points. There's an arc from i to j if and only if the line segment connecting i and j deviates less than the maximum error from the points in between.